# is Python called differently via Jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins

I did notice something strange on my python server running jenkins. Basically if I run a script, which has dependencies (I use python via Brew), from console, it works fine.

But when I run it via Jenkins, I get an error because that package was not found.
When I call the script, I use `python -m py.test -s myscript.py`

Is there a gotcha when using Jenkins, and call python as I do? I would expect that a command called in the bash section of Jenkins, would execute as if it was running in console, but from the result that I get, it seems that is not true.

When I check for `which python`, I get back `/usr/local/bin/python`; which has the symlink to the brew version. If I `echo $PYTHONPATH` I get back the same path.

One interesting thing though, is that if on Jenkins I call explicitly either `/usr/local/bin/python -m` or `/usr/bin/python` ; I get an error saying that there is no python there; but if I just use `python -m`, it works. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: What does `echo $PYTHONPATH` say?

Comment: I get back the path "usr/local/bin/python"; which has the symlink to the python version via Brew.

Comment: Is the `$PYTHONPATH` directory where the modules you're trying to import are installed?

Comment: Where is the brew version?  In your home directory?  What user is jenkins running as?  Might be a permissions issue or path issue (ie. `~/python` resolves to something different for jenkins than for you)

Comment: @JohnZwinck No, the PYTHONPATH does not include what is installed via Brew; which lives in /usr/bin/cellar I believe. I will try to add this folder too.

Comment: @BrendanAbel the brew version is in /usr/local/cellar, not in my home directory. Jenkins is running as the current user (user); The curious thing is that THE SAME machine has 2 different behaviors; because on this slave, if I run the script via console, it runs fine; but if I go on the jenkins web UI, and run a job on this slave (which is the only one that I have, BTW), it fail with the error that I did mention earlier

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is running your jobs as a different user, and typically on a different host (unless you let your Jenkins run on your local host and don't use slaves to run your jobs).  Resulting from these two aspects you will have also a different environment (variables like `HOME`, `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, and all the other environment stuff like locales etc.).

To find out the **host**, let a shell in the job execute `hostname`.

To find out the **Jenkins user**, let a shell in the job execute `id`.

To find out the **environment**, let a shell in the job execute `set` (which will produce a lot of output).

My guess would be that in your case the modules you are trying to use are not installed on the Jenkins host.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to check as you suggested; but from what I read, it is a fact that Jenkins may be running differently from a regular user running in console. I have one slave; on this slave I did install my packages; and if I run the python script, it is correctly performed, but when I run it via Jenkins UI, it fail. It make no sense that Jenkins can't find /usr/bin/python or usr/local/bin/python, since via console I can do "which pythion" and I get the correct path. Just passing "python" without full path works, but then it won't find the installed packages needed by the script

Comment: If you care to share what `hostname`, `id` and `set` give as output from within the Jenkins and from outside of it, that could give some hints on where to go next.

Comment: I did actually solve the issue, creating symlinks to point to python via a shell script called on the shell section of the Jenkins job. This is forcing Jenkins to use "slave python" without have to be concerned of how it get called. The bash script set the symlink and call the python script correctly. Not sure why Jenkins is acting in this way, but I have a way to work around the problem. Thanks for your pointer about checking the environment!